# JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [<]

Tags: json, ios4, runtime-error, sbjson

i am new to JSON Parsing. I am using SBJson 3.1 and trying to fetch data in response to which I got above error. I have searched alot on Google, but no one has ever asked or explained what actually error `Illegal Start of Token` means. So please can somebody explain me this? And how can I debug this error?

The code I have written so far is:

```cs
-(IBAction) Start:(id)sender
{
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[responseData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];

[connection release];
responseData = nil;
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]  initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[responseData release];

NSDictionary *dict = [responseString JSONValue];

}
```

Comment: What is your JSON input?

Comment: I am just providing URL "xyz/Final/webserviceName.php" to fetch the whole data for testing purpose.

Comment: Oh yes, I can *totally* use that to tell you what the problem is. How about telling me what the DATA is?

Comment: data is in format: [{"UserId":"1","UserName":"Mahnor ahmad","Address":"Block-l Naz, Kh","EmailId":"maha@xyz.com","Pswd":"1234567","Dob":"2012-06-05","Gender":"female","SecAns":"biryani","CountryId":"3","City":"karachi","ProfessionId":"3","SecQId":"1","zip":"0"}]. there is lot more   like this.

Comment: And you're sure that's exactly what the function is reading? If you replace the parse function with an output function, is that what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all instead of:

```
#define URL @"http://xyz...."
```

and using it as,

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

I just copied it to:

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:http://xyz....]];

Secondly, the problem was that json string returned through web service was not correct. When I printed response data, it was something like this:

`<3c68746d 6c3e0a20 2020203c 68656164 3e0a2020 20203c2f 68656164 3e0a2020 20203c62 6f64793e 0a5b7b22 55736572 4964223a 2231222c 22557365 724e616d 65223a22 4d616861 20497a68.....>`

[This](http://jsonlint.com/) link helped me alot to understand what does "Illegal Start of Token" mean.

On web service, following is written:

```
<html><head></head><body>[
{
    "UserId": "1", .....
```

Error raised was:

`Parse error on line 1:
<html><head></head><
^
Expecting '{', '['`